# How can I know from which Google account (Email id) user purchased a product in my app?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, multiple-accounts

Suppose a user has 3 accounts and one of them is in the app purchase account.
Then when this user purchases a product from my app, how can I know from which account the in app purchase happened?
Can I get the email id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is impossible. Google does not give this information. You can know from where is user, user device model, or something like this, but not who is user!

Comment: so how can i uniquely identyfy who has purchase product in my app ?

Comment: You must store authenticated user info in your server (backend) before sending purchase request to google then you can validating user based on your own backend data. Google play store only validating based on user device not email address